# Randomize OrderBy with EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I am getting a list of people in a EntityDataSource and binding this to a repeater.
I want to order them randomly so the people are not always displayed in the same order.  What options do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 list.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code, for anyone interested.

```
   protected void MyDataSource_QueryCreated(object sender, QueryCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var members = e.Query.Cast<EntityFramework.Member>();
        e.Query = from member in members.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                  select member;  
    }
```